# TypeError: SQLite3 can only bind numbers, strings, bigints, buffers, and null

Tags: javascript, sqlite

there is an sql select method being called but im not sure what the parameters passed indicate here

```
selectMethod({ a: b });
```

this is failing to run in sqlite with error:

> TypeError: SQLite3 can only bind numbers, strings, bigints, buffers, and null

.. worked fine on mysql

Comment: SQLite is not MySQL. I’m curious why you expect non-ISO SQL syntax and features to be universally supported…

Comment: There isn't enough context to say what's wrong. Can you please edit the question to mention what exact library you are using, and what values these variables have? Make sure you include the SQL code and table structure.

Answer (score 1):

for me it seems that the function you are using internally tries to bind a value that is not one of these supported types (numbers, strings, bigints, buffers, and null), causing the error.
Make sure that the value being passed ({a: b} in this case) is of a supported type according to the SQLite3 documentation. You may need to convert or modify the value to match the expected types for SQLite3.

Let me know if it works

Comment: thanks for your answer .. im new to js and im not sure what {a: b} means .. does this denote a dictionary or something ?

Comment: @user12332695 That's an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics).